# query returns unexpected results

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, operator-precedence

I feel like this search query is not working as I imagined it would. I want to be certain that the only items selected are those with `ksisoldby` identical (though case-insensitive, thus `ILIKE`) to `$user`. And the the other fields specified with the `AND`s and `OR`s are possible ways this selection could be narrowed down.

```
"SELECT 
id,
status,
customer_id,
shipping_address_id,
order_number,
reference,
ship_via_id,
order_date :: date,
due_date :: date,
created,
sales_tax,
freight,
taxable,
nontaxable,
job_name,
order_description,
ship_to_name,
ship_to_address1,
ship_to_address2,
ship_to_city,
ship_to_state,
ship_to_zipcode,
name,
address1,
address2,
city,
state,
zipcode,
act_ship_date,
ksisoldby
FROM sales_orders 
WHERE ksisoldby ILIKE '".$user."'
AND (order_description ilike 
'%".implode("%' AND order_description like '%", $search)."%')
OR (order_number ilike 
'%".implode("%' AND order_number like '%", $search)."%')
OR (name ilike 
'%".implode("%' AND name like '%", $search)."%')
OR (reference ilike 
'%".implode("%' AND name like '%", $search)."%')
ORDER BY order_number DESC";
```

Have I done this correctly, and it is my data that is not set up correctly, or are these `AND` and/or `OR` statements overriding the `WHERE` clause? Thanks for the help.

Comment: First of all you can dramatically shorten the query string by writing select * instead of listing every single column. Also, can you explain what type of data kissoldby is?

Comment: It looks like you have a typo.  Your query reads `ksisoldby` and your question says `kissoldby`.

Comment: @redelman431 but that is not everything in the table.. wouldn't that slow performance to select things i do not need?  `ksisoldby` identifies the user, so only results from his or her records are shown.

Comment: @SomeKittens  Sorry, should both be `ksisoldby`. Fixed.

Comment: Not sure how much difference it will make ,but you're using both `like` and `ilike`

Comment: @freefaller Yes, should probably all be `ILIKE` Thanks -

Comment: Is that the solution? If so, I will add as an answer

Comment: @freefaller no, that is not the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keyword here is [**operator precedence**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE). `AND` binds before `OR`.

```
WHERE ksisoldby ILIKE '".$user."'
AND (
     order_description ilike '%".implode("%'
     AND order_description like '%", $search)."%')
  OR order_number ilike '%".implode("%'
     AND order_number like '%", $search)."%'
  OR name ilike '%".implode("%'
     AND name like '%", $search)."%'
  OR reference ilike '%".implode("%'
     AND name like '%", $search)."%'
    )
```

All items in the `WHERE` clause are evaluated to one boolean result. If you

> want to be certain that the only items selected are those with ksisoldby identical [...] to $user

then you have to wrap the `OR`'ed criteria into parenthesis or they will offer **alternative ways** to qualify.

On the other hand, you can remove the parenthesis around the `AND`'ed pairs like I demonstrate.

I added (syntactically irrelevant) white space and line breaks to make it clearer.

---

BTW - as this came up in the comments - if you don't want all columns from the table, listing the ones you want (like you have it) is the optimal way.

---

I would also consider to use [**prepared statements**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-prepare.html) (or server-side functions with parameters) instead of building one big query strings to **prevent SQL injection**. Your framework probably offers some way to do this. Or you can do it manually.

While you keep building query strings, use [`quote_literal()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) to sanitize user input.

Comment: this works fantastically. thank you. I read the article about prepared statements and wonder if you could take the time to make a simplified example using this query.. i get that is actually another question, but i'm very curious. thanks a million for the help!

Comment: @thomas: Glad it works! As you said - it's a different question. I suggest you just open another one. That's more useful to the general public.