# PostgreSQL prepare/execute statement written correctly using php?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I have heard that using `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE` in a SQL statement will sanitize user-supplied data into something incapable of SQL injection. Is this true?

My original query is this:

```
$query = 
"SELECT * FROM sales_orders 
WHERE ksisoldby ILIKE '".$user."'";
```

This is my best guess for changing it to a prepare/execute statement:

```
 <?php
$id = $_POST['id'];
$search = $_POST['user_supplied_search_term'];

PREPARE search_query_function (varchar, varchar) AS

SELECT * FROM sales_orders 
WHERE ksisoldby ILIKE '$1'";

EXECUTE search_query_function($id, $search);
?>
```

Is this written/invoked correctly? There are also some built in php objects (`PDO`) that I have read about. Should I be using those instead or in conjunction? Thanks for help on this sort of broad question.

Comment: Yes, you should be using PDO instead for new code.

Comment: This is not valid PHP syntax.

Comment: @nickb yeah, you're right. now that i think about it, i'm lost as to how to incorporate the `prepare/execute` into php.. what i have now doesn't make sense, I see..

Comment: I think you should **simplify your example** to learn how to use prepared statements. We have discussed the [SQL query itself already](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11493106/939860).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Definitely a good idea. Fixed.

Comment: +1 Useful and clear now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You incorporate `prepare()` and `execute()` in PHP by using prepared statements, which are available when you use [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php). This extensions is responsible for creating the appropriate `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE` statements for your database according to the database driver you have selected.

Here is an example adapted from [the PHP manual](http://us.php.net/pdo.prepare) using `prepare()` and `execute()`.

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM sales_orders 
    WHERE ksisoldby ILIKE ?');
$sth->execute( array( $_POST['user_supplied_search_term']));
```

This will take care of the parameter escaping for you and create an SQL statement similar to:

```
SELECT * FROM sales_orders 
    WHERE ksisoldby ILIKE 'something'
```

So you need to adapt the above code to include your SQL statement within the call to `prepare()`, which requires you to add placeholders to where you want your parameters to be included. Then you call `execute()`, which will add in the values passed to it.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. couple questions: will I supply the `PREPARE` statement with values always using an array of values. Do I need to set up `$dbh` or is it ready to accept the `PREPARE` method without additional preparation? Is there any advantage to this besides the prevention of SQL injection? Thanks again!

Comment: You need to initialize `$dbh` by calling PDO's constructor, see the manual for more information on that. You never form the `PREPARE` statement by yourself - You let PDO handle that for you. So, you just supply the SQL statement you want to execute, and let PDO do the rest.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [pg_query_params](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php), easy to use and safe.